# IE alternative to Array.prototype.find()

Tags: javascript

I previously wrote some code which matches uploaded files to their relevant clientID's, and displays them in a table to show which files are being assigned to which clients. The trouble is I tested this on Chrome and Safari as per the job spec and it works fine.

The problem is that this doesn't work on IE due to it not supporting `Array.prototype.find()` and they have now asked for it to be compatible with IE.

I have looked at other questions, but the answers were specific to their situation, often giving examples of other ways to do what they are looking for.

What would be the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

```
var item = clientList.find(function(item) {

    return item.UniqueID == ClientID;

});
```

Comment: There's a polyfill for [`find` on the MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I looked at that before but I am unsure how to use it. I have tested putting it in the code but still I get the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried. You'd have to put it into the code before you use it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks. I just found the client changed the server on me so had been trying to get it to work on the old server!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own find function, the important part is to break loop when you match element.

```js
var data = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}];

function altFind(arr, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var match = callback(arr[i]);
    if (match) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}

var result = altFind(data, function(e) {
  return e.id == 2;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Don't extend built-in prototypes unless you are polyfilling an existing API.

Comment: @Jon Koops Updated my answer.

Comment: Why would you write your own when a (correct, tested, spec-compliant) polyfill is readily available?

Comment: @Bergi OP said he couldn't get polyfill to work and i wanted to provide easier solution.

Comment: @NenadVracar Hi, Thanks for your answer, I have tested it and it is working. Very helpful. Regarding polyfill, that is also working now, I had been uploading to the wrong server. Doh!

Comment: @NenadVracar You just saved my life today. Thanks